# How to set default value if joining table data not exist in laravel?

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel-5.7

I have two tables. `product` and `inventory`. I want to LEFT JOIN `product` with `inventory`. There is also an summation operation based on the inventory.stock.

My code is given below,

```
DB::table('product')
    ->leftjoin('inventory','product.id','=','inventory.product_id')
    ->select('product.id as id',
            'product.name as name',
            'product.color as color',
            'product.unit_price as unit_price',
            DB::raw('SUM(inventory.stock)::integer as available_stock'))
     ->groupBy('product.id')
     ->get();
```

My problem is there are many products for which there are no row in inventory table. In that case the `available_stock` is giving me `null`. Instead of `null` I want to show a default string. Something like "not stocked" or "0". How can I achieve that?

I am using postgresql.

Comment: `(case when inventory.product_id is null then 0 else SUM(inventory.stock)::integer end) as available_stock` you can use something like this.

Comment: you can also use like this 
DB::raw('SUM(inventory.stock)::integer as available_stock')->default('0');

Comment: @SavajPatel.. it is giving error. Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression::default()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way you can set the default value for available stock.

This will give zero when inventory is not available.

```
DB::table('product')
->leftjoin('inventory','product.id','=','inventory.product_id')
->select('product.id as id',
        'product.name as name',
        'product.color as color',
        'product.unit_price as unit_price',
        DB::raw('(case when inventory.product_id is null then 0 else SUM(inventory.stock)::integer end) as available_stock'))
 ->groupBy('product.id')
 ->get();
```

Comment: It is giving inventory.product_id must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function.

Comment: Anyway I added the inventory.product_id in groupBy function and it is working. Thank you very much